# A100 tensorflow gpu error: "Failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: initialization error"

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, nvidia-docker

I am trying to run tensorflow with gpu support in a docker on a virtual machine. I have tried lots of online solutions including:

- tried different docker images of versions of tensorflow: 2.6, 2.4, 1.15, 1.14
- built tensorflow from source inside the container based on this guide several times with different bazel flags https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source for 2.6 and 1.14
- tried to make the GPU visible by these kinds of commands:[TensorFlow : failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48658204/tensorflow-failed-call-to-cuinit-cuda-error-no-device)
- used nvidia tensorflow docker

none of the solutions work for me, here some steps:

I verified that drivers and cuda and cudnn toolkit are installed inside the container using nvidia-smi and nvcc -V:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Python version is :
**Python 3.8.10**

and tensorflow version is:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
tf.__version__
'2.6.0'
```

The error appears with:
tf.config.list_physical_devices()

[image]

So the GPU is somehow not visible to the tensorflow. All tensorflow builds return the same error:

```
 E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:271] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: initialization error
```

but for example for 1.14 there is an additional comment regarding the CPU type:

```
Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 AVX512F FMA
```

[image]

The GPU is a A100 and the CPU is Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6226R.

What is going on here? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realized that the GPU has a multi-instance feature:

[image]

Therefore, the GPU instances should be configured:

```
sudo nvidia-smi mig -cgi 0 -C
```

[image]

and afterwards when calling nvidia-smi you get:

[image]

And the problem is solved!

Comment: Thanks @Farnaz. This procedure got Tensorflow to recognize the GPU for me.